# APIM custom profiles

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We'd like to create a custom APIM profile that only install/enables the Publisher, Key Manager and Traffic Manager on a single jvm. The gateway (manager and worker nodes) and Store will be running on separate JVMs.
How can I create a new profile?

And also, the docs state that the profiles only enable/disable the osgi bundles belonging to a profile, but that the web applications are still available (and I quess the web services too, since they are packages as .war archives). Can I remove the unused web apps on the different profiles? E.g. remove the gateway and publisher web apps on the store instance. Is this documented somewhere?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We'd like to create a custom APIM profile that only install/enables
>   the Publisher, Key Manager and Traffic Manager on a single jvm. The
>   gateway (manager and worker nodes) and Store will be running on
>   separate JVMs. How can I create a new profile?

Running multiple profiles in one server hasn't supported.

> Can I remove the unused web apps on the different profiles?

Yes, you can remove the WARs specific to other profiles.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. I didn't now you could provide multiple profiles to the same instance. So what you're saying is I could start with `./wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-publisher -Dprofile=api-store` to enable the publisher and store profiles on one jvm

Comment: @DannyKruitbosch. Running multiple profiles in one server hasn't supported.